# wxWigets create wxPanel changing with the context

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

My software is based on just a frame dividen into two panels
For example, if I click the button "let's draw", the first panel on the left should becone a toolbox (with colour palette, brush and so on), the second panel should become a paint like panel
If I click the button "let's sing", on the left should appear four button, on the right the song to sing

What's the best tecnique to obtain that result?

1. I render the four panel (two for drawing, two for singing). The two I use are in position 0,0; the other are in position -1000,0
2. I create some function changeLeftPanelIntoDrawing(), changeRightPanelIntoDrawing(), changeLeftPanelIntoSinging(), changeRightPanelIntoSinging(), then I call them on click
3. Other hint?

Answer (score 0):

In wxWidgets 3.0 you have [wxSimplebook](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_simplebook.html) which allows you to just add different pages (i.e. arbitrary windows) to it and switch between them. If you're using an earlier version you can still just drop the contents of [wx/simplebook.h](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/include/wx/simplebook.h) into your project and use it, it's a very simple class and you can read its code in 30 seconds to see how it is implemented.